# Regain access to phone with Family Link parental control

Tags: password, motorola, google-family-link

My phone Motorola E22i (XT2239) did an update and is asking for my password (not a PIN). The password is requested on the lock screen. It's never looked like this before.

[image]

I tried my Google account password and my dad tried his password, but neither works. We also tried resetting it, but it has reset protection, so we can't even do that.

What password does it want?

Comment: It may have a Motorola account.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't remember signing up for that.

Comment: That looks like [a password screen when the device is encrypted with FDE (Full-Disk Encryption)](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk). It usually asks for the lock screen password. Otherwise, you may want to try "default_password".

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you can reset the screen unlock password. I havent tried it

> **Unlock a Motorola Phone without Losing Data by ADM**
> A simple and convenient tool that can be used to accomplish this task is Android Device Manager – ADM. Your Motorola phone, like any other active Android device, is linked to your Google account. The main point of this method is to leverage access to your Google account and password, to get around the original problem. You can unlock the Motorola phone password without resetting it on a computer or another phone, but you need to provide a stable internet connection for the duration of the process.
>
> Step 1: Type the address [www.google.com/android/find](http://www.google.com/android/find) in the web browser on any device.
>
> Step 2: Sign in with your unique Google account username and password.
>
> Step 3: Google will start to search for your device. If you have multiple devices registered on the same account, choose the one you want to unlock from the list.
>
> Step 4: Three options will appear on the screen, click on one that allows you to change the password.
>
> `Choose Change the Screen-unlock Password`
>
> Step 5: Empty window will appear. Enter a temporary password, and click on the Lock again. If the process is successful, you will get a confirmation message.
>
> Step 6: On your locked Motorola enter the previously used temporary password, and your device will be unlocked. You will be able to use your phone any without limitations and set up a new password for permanent use if you so decide.

From [How to Unlock my Motorola Phone with/without Factory Reset](https://www.imobie.com/android-unlock/get-into-a-locked-motorola-phone.htm)

I am not associated with this website.